# Facebook Login button causes "Uncaught error

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I've implemented the Facebook Login button in my web application like this:

js.js:

```
// Facebook Login
try {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'myappidhere',
            xfbml: true,
            cookie: true,
            version: 'v2.10'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };
} catch (e) {
    throw(e)
}

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nb_NO/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

index.php:

```
echo "    <fb:login-button scope='public_profile,email' onlogin='FacebookLogin();' size='large'></fb:login-button>";
```

Recently I've been getting this error when loading the page: I've searched for this error but only found it in connection with React.js. If there's React involved here, it isn't loaded by me. Therefore I don't think I can use the non-minified environment it is referring to?

```
Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev 
environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
 at a (_vYlPJR1onv.js:44)
 at a (_vYlPJR1onv.js:121)
 at x (_vYlPJR1onv.js:193)
 at Object.b.post [as log] (_vYlPJR1onv.js:193)
 at a.logVital (_vYlPJR1onv.js:219)
 at _vYlPJR1onv.js:293
 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
 at IntersectionObserver.e.threshold (_vYlPJR1onv.js:293)
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't from you, see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/780374708825818/
The problem is happening to everyone who use the facebook connect button (See pinterest login page for example which have the exact same error)